# Can rails grouped_collection_select 'options' be styled?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap and ruby on rails for back-end.

I have searched a lot but did not find an answer to it.

In my web app, I need to implement dependent dropdown(like country and state). For that I have used "**grouped_collection_select**". However, the **options** are dynamically generated and I need to apply styling to the options like border image, divider image etc. I wish to know if that is possible? Or is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `grouped_collection_select(object, method, collection, group_method, group_label_method, option_key_method, option_value_method, options = {}, html_options = {}` this is the syntax for `grouped_collection_select` and there is option of `html_options`. SO you should be able to apply style

Comment: Thanks @Sontya It works fine but can we apply properties like border-image to options that are generated?

Comment: please post some of your code, it will help to understand

Comment: @Sontya I wish to implement this dropdown : http://prntscr.com/6huwuj

I am not finding any solution to style "options" of select

Comment: Suppose you want to add style based on options selected, supoose you select `option1` then call a function `toggle_style(selected) { if(selected == "option1" then color: red, image: image_path else if  selected == "option2" then color: blue, image: image_path}`. Something like this you can try. Be more specific what you want, So I can help you

Comment: Hey @Sontya I do not wish to add styles based on options selected. I want to style the options themselves to make them appear like I wish them to in this snapshot prntscr.com/6huwuj

Comment: `grouped_collection_select(object, method, collection, group_method, group_label_method, option_key_method, option_value_method, options = {}, { class: "option_style" })` try this and whatever style you want you can give in css with the `class_name` as `option_style`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can!

```
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label 'blah' %>
  <%= f.grouped_collection_select :category_id, Category.roots.order(:name), :children, :name, :id, :name, {include_blank: true}, {class: "form-control"} %> 
</div>
```

braces must be around include_blank too otherwise it won't work. Also won't work if you change class=field to class=form-control. And there are a billion other scenarios when it won't work but I only tried these :)

'njoy!